# Hibernate Envers: disable auditing temporarily

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-envers, auditing

I've created an entities copier in a project where envers is enable but for this copier I don't need the auditing: is there a way to disable temporarily the envers auditing?

I know that there are listener that works as interceptors (before the audit trigger) but I need also know where auditing is triggered from (for example the controller that call the service where auditing is triggered).

I don't know if it's possible.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Envers registers a set of event listeners that are triggered by [Hibernates Event system](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#events-events).

In order to implement conditional auditing ([see envers documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.3/devguide/en-US/html/ch15.html#d5e4362)), you need to replace these listeners with your own implementation. The following [event types](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/javadocs/org/hibernate/event/spi/EventType.html) trigger enver's listeners:

- EventType.POST_INSERT
- EventType.PRE_UPDATE
- EventType.POST_UPDATE
- EventType.POST_DELETE
- EventType.POST_COLLECTION_RECREATE
- EventType.PRE_COLLECTION_REMOVE
- EventType.PRE_COLLECTION_UPDATE

Since you want to skip auditing only on copied entities you only need to replace `org.hibernate.envers.event.spi.EnversPostInsertEventListenerImpl`.

In your entity you add a transient field that acts as a flag. This way you can determine within your listener implementation if the entity was copied.

```
public class YourEntity {

    @Transient
    private boolean copy;

    public boolean isCopy() {
        return copy;
    }

    public void setCopy(boolean copy) {
        this.copy = copy;
    }
}
```

Then you implement your listener by extending the default one:

```
public class CustomPostInsertListener extends EnversPostInsertEventListenerImpl {

    public CustomPostInsertListener(EnversService enversService) {
        super(enversService);
    }

    @Override public void onPostInsert(PostInsertEvent event) {
        if (event.getEntity() instanceof YourEntity
                && ((YourEntity) event.getEntity()).isCopy()) {
            // Ignore this entity
            return;
        }
        super.onPostInsert(event);
    }
}
```

In your copier you need to set the `copy` flag for your entities.

```
public YourEntity copyEntity(YourEntity entityToCopy){
    YourEntity newEntity;
    //... your copy logic

    newEntity.setCopy(true);
    return newEntity;
}
```

Then you need to create your own implementation of [org.hibernate.integrator.spi.Integrator](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/javadocs/org/hibernate/integrator/spi/Integrator.html). The Easiest is to extend `org.hibernate.envers.event.spi.EnversIntegrator`:

```
package com.your.project.audit;

public class EnversCustomIntegrator extends EnversIntegrator {

    public static final String  AUTO_REGISTER   = "hibernate.listeners.envers.autoRegister";
    private AuditConfiguration  enversConfiguration;

    @Override
    public void integrate(org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration configuration, SessionFactoryImplementor sessionFactory, SessionFactoryServiceRegistry serviceRegistry) {



        final EventListenerRegistry listenerRegistry = serviceRegistry.getService(EventListenerRegistry.class);
        listenerRegistry.addDuplicationStrategy(EnversListenerDuplicationStrategy.INSTANCE);

        enversConfiguration = AuditConfiguration.getFor(configuration, serviceRegistry.getService(ClassLoaderService.class));

        if (enversConfiguration.getEntCfg().hasAuditedEntities()) {
            listenerRegistry.appendListeners(EventType.POST_DELETE, new EnversPostDeleteEventListenerImpl(enversConfiguration));
            listenerRegistry.appendListeners(EventType.POST_INSERT, new CustomPostInsertListener(enversConfiguration));
            listenerRegistry.appendListeners(EventType.POST_UPDATE, new EnversPostUpdateEventListenerImpl(enversConfiguration));
            listenerRegistry.appendListeners(EventType.POST_COLLECTION_RECREATE, new EnversPostCollectionRecreateEventListenerImpl(enversConfiguration));
            listenerRegistry.appendListeners(EventType.PRE_COLLECTION_REMOVE, new EnversPreCollectionRemoveEventListenerImpl(enversConfiguration));
            listenerRegistry.appendListeners(EventType.PRE_COLLECTION_UPDATE, new EnversPreCollectionUpdateEventListenerImpl(enversConfiguration));
        }

    }
}
```

Lastly you need to add your Integrator implementation in the META-INF/services/org.hibernate.integrator.spi.Integrator file.

```
com.your.project.audit.EnversCustomIntegrator
```